# Error with basic tensorflow optimisation example

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm fairly new to tensorflow, tried to calculate argmin of a quadratic function. I want to see the value of x and y after each iteration. Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1.0,name="x")
y = x**2 - 4*x + 3
alpha = 0.05

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = alpha).minimize(y)
num_epochs = 20

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print("Epoch: %d" %epoch)
        opt,x,result = sess.run([optimizer,x,y])
        print(result)
```

The error I get is **argument has invalid type , must be a string or Tensor.**

It works if I don't try to get the value of x, just y and opt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line

```
opt,x,result = sess.run([optimizer,x,y])
```

you assign the evaluated result of the *x* operation to variable *x* - thus, in the next iteration, *x* is no longer `tf.Variable(1.0,name="x")` but the result from the previous iteration. Just use another name for the variable and it should work.